# What does ガッポォオォイ mean?

Tags: meaning, contractions, anime

I tried searching in jisho.org with different iteratons of the オ to no avail.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

As others have answered the `ォオォ` part is only to transcribe the elongation of the preceding `ポ` (it could be written `ガッポーーーイ` instead to the same effect), so the "actual" word you're looking for is `ガッポイ`.

`ガッポイ`, to most people<sup>1</sup>, will refer to a schoolyardish "game" typically played by boys. It consists in managing to slide one's hand between an "adversary"'s legs, from behind, and raising one's hand up against their crotch while shouting 「ガッポイ！」, slightly [akin to](https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2139321045591450101#2142897950599738703) the [カンチョー](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanch%C5%8D) prank.

Here however, it seems to be a word peculiar to this series (「僕のヒーローアカデミア」) and a [screen annotation](https://twitter.com/thukihimiandao/status/1228598824265900032?s=20) in this very scene  spells out that it is, in this setting, meant as a contraction of `[学校]{がっこう}っぽい`.

`っぽい` indicates something that has a strong component of (or similarity to) what it suffixes (so here, `[学校]{がっこう}`). In other word, `[学校]{がっこう}っぽい` would designate something very "[**schooly**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schooly#Adjective)", or peculiar to school.
It wouldn't make much sense out of context, but it seems that in *My Hero Academia* the characters, while being students, spend a lot of time fighting and don't often perform activities typical of a traditional school environment, and since they've just been anounced a [cultural festival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_festival_(Japan)) (「[文化祭]{ぶんかさい}」） (which is an event very typical of a school environment in Japan) would take place, they shout `ガッポイ！`, which thus could be translated to something like *"How schooly!"*.

<sub>[Source (jp) with illustrations](https://xaircraft.jp/heroaca-gp)</sub>

---

<sub>1. The blog post I cited as [source](https://xaircraft.jp/heroaca-gp) hypothesises that the series creator may have chosen to make up this particular word because he wasn't aware of the existing "real life" `ガッポイ` game.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Googling **ガッポォオォイ** led me to this page:

[ガッポォオォイ！JR秋葉原駅構内で...](https://blog.goo.ne.jp/omaketeki/e/3effb9bbbb5fe99a130a6e0fbd0d258c/?img=f070a19c73f932d6331d595b6998af17)
which gives this explanation:

> **ガッポォオォイ**！（※**学校っぽい**の略）

**っぽい** being a common suffix, some kind of slang expression added to convey an idea of "similarity" or "likeness", often translatable as "-like" or "~ish" in English...

Examples:

- 学校っぽい (school-like)
- 子供っぽい (childish)
- 熱っぽい (feverish)
- 安っぽい (cheap-looking)
- 水っぽい (watery)
- 滑りっぽい (slippery)
- 色っぽい (sexy/erotic)